# Spotify playlist images does not populate to App via REST API. Can someone assist with this issue?

Tags: image, api, rest, spotify, playlist

We have created a app and are trying to access playlists via REST API but the response from Spotify does not contain images, we get a empty value for the key images.

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2015, the `images` key returns mosaic images for those playlists without custom cover art.